# How can I set timeout for requests using Moya pod?

Tags: ios, swift, moya

I'm using Swift 3 and the [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya/) pod.

I configured everything I needed using the [Basic Usage](https://github.com/Moya/Moya/blob/master/docs/Examples/Basic.md), but I didn't find any function or variable that I can set the timeout (for every requests or for a specific request).

How can I do this?

Comment: This issue explains a way to do it: https://github.com/Moya/Moya/issues/743

Comment: Sorry for delay. I tested and it worked. Thanks! Write an answer explaining and I choose as the correct answer! :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[haydarKarkin](https://github.com/haydarKarkin) has provided an answer to this in a [comment on GitHub](https://github.com/Moya/Moya/issues/743#issuecomment-258643529). The code snippets below are copied directly from his comment.

---

You can create a custom configuration for a Moya provider by creating a custom Alamofire Session Manager:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class DefaultAlamofireManager: Alamofire.SessionManager {
    static let sharedManager: DefaultAlamofireManager = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20 // as seconds, you can set your request timeout
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 20 // as seconds, you can set your resource timeout
        configuration.requestCachePolicy = .useProtocolCachePolicy
        return DefaultAlamofireManager(configuration: configuration)
    }()    
}
```

Then include the custom Alamofire Manager when declaring your Provider:

```
let Provider = MoyaProvider<GithubAPI>(endpointClosure: endpointClosure,
        manager: DefaultAlamofireManager.sharedManager,
        plugins: [NetworkActivityPlugin(networkActivityClosure: networkActivityClosure)])
```

Comment: endpointClosure and plugins are optional parameters to the MoyaProvider initializer. See https://github.com/Moya/Moya/blob/master/docs/Providers.md#advanced-usage for more info.

Comment: This is actually incorrect. Neither `timeoutIntervalForRequest` or `timeoutIntervalForResource` match the behavior of `URLRequest`'s `timeoutInterval`.

Answer (score 7):

@askielboe's great answer updated for **Alamofire 5**:

```
class DefaultAlamofireSession: Alamofire.Session {
    static let shared: DefaultAlamofireSession = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.headers = .default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20 // as seconds, you can set your request timeout
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 20 // as seconds, you can set your resource timeout
        configuration.requestCachePolicy = .useProtocolCachePolicy
        return DefaultAlamofireSession(configuration: configuration)
    }()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can Manage the Session Configuration in your session Manager and decide  the requests that use a different timeout value.

```
import Foundation
import Moya

struct MyNetworkManager {
    static let provider = MoyaProvider<MyService>()

    static func request(
        target: MyService,
        success successCallback: @escaping (JSON) -> Void,
        error errorCallback: @escaping (Error) -> Void,
        failure failureCallback: @escaping (MoyaError) -> Void
        ) {
      //Check request
        switch target {
        case .quickAnswer:
            provider.manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 2
        default:
            provider.manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = Manager.default.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest
        }
            provider.request(target) { result in
                let url = target.path
                switch result {
                case let .success(response):
                    do {
                        let _ = try response.filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()
                        let json = try JSON(response.mapJSON())
                        successCallback(json)
                    }
                    catch  {
                        errorCallback(error)
                    }
                case let .failure(error):
                    failureCallback(error)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't look like a good solution if you're making multiple calls simultaneously.

Answer (score 4):

With Use of latest Moya and Alamofire versions,
 Set session parameter of provider with custom Alamofire session.

```
class DefaultAlamofireSession: Alamofire.Session {
    static let shared: DefaultAlamofireSession = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.headers = .default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30 // as seconds, you can set your request timeout
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30 // as seconds, you can set your resource timeout
        configuration.requestCachePolicy = .useProtocolCachePolicy
        return DefaultAlamofireSession(configuration: configuration)
    }()
}

let provider = MoyaProvider<OpenApi>(session: DefaultAlamofireSession.shared, plugins: [authPlugin])
```